# Pandas - Remove value from all rows except when it appears in first position of ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, group-by

I have a dataframe that I have to keep first row per ID if value is 0. If other row position of ID equals 0 then remove. So the code should remove 0 from all rows except when it appears in first position of ID.

Here is an example of the input:

| ID | Sign | Tenure | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Positive | 0 | First position of ID 001, then keep |
| 001 | Negative | -245 |  |
| 001 | Positive | 54 |  |
| 002 | Positive | 62 |  |
| 002 | Negative | 23 |  |
| 002 | Positive | 0 | Not first position of ID 002, then remove row |
| 002 | Positive | 432 |  |
| 002 | Negative | -345 |  |

...

Here is an example of the output:

| ID | Sign | Tenure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Positive | 0 |
| 001 | Negative | -245 |
| 001 | Positive | 54 |
| 002 | Positive | 62 |
| 002 | Negative | 23 |
| 002 | Positive | 432 |
| 002 | Negative | -345 |

Tried groupby with for loop and if statement without success. Basically there are 2 options for each ID:

If 0 appears in the first row, keep

If 0 appears in another position, delete row

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2},
        'Sign': {0: 'Positive', 1: 'Negative', 2: 'Positive', 3: 'Positive', 4: 'Negative', 5: 'Positive', 6: 'Positive', 7: 'Negative'},
        'Tenure': {0: 0, 1: -245, 2: 54, 3: 62, 4: 23, 5: 0, 6: 432, 7: -345}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

make condition by using `duplicated`

```
df[~(df.duplicated('ID') & df['Tenure'].eq(0))]
```

output:

```
    ID  Sign    Tenure
0   1   Positive    0
1   1   Negative    -245
2   1   Positive    54
3   2   Positive    62
4   2   Negative    23
6   2   Positive    432
7   2   Negative    -345
```

Comment: Thanks, I am missing how to keep the value of '0' if it appears in the first row of each ID. Basically there are 2 options:
If 0 appears in the first row, keep.
If 0 appears in another position, delete row